# Appending position based upon each race result

Tags: python, list, append

I could be completely wrong here with how to go about this, but basically I need to at first create a dictionary of names with empty lists of values for a race.

```
contestants = {[("Alice", []),("Dennis", []), ("Bob", []), ("Eva", []), ("Clare", [])]}
```

I'm assuming that is it how I do it ^^

and then I need to be able to append the values to the empty lists and sort the the positions based upon the overall score.

```
{'Dennis': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5], 'Alice': [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2], 'Bob': [3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1], 'Eva': [5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3], 'Clare': [1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4]}
```

Above are the score that each player has had and it has also been sorted for them.

```
def seriesscores(racescores):
contestants = {[("Alice", []),("Dennis", []), ("Bob", []), ("Eva", []), ("Clare", [])]}
contestants.append(racescores[1])
return contestants
```

I have currently been testing this code above and it keep displaying a error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in seriesscores
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

All I'm looking for right now is a way to append the scores to the empty lists, I assume I could just sort it then with this code:

```
return sorted(contestants, key=lambda x: (sum(x[1])))
```

Am I on the correct track?

Comment: Why on earth are the names hard-coded? Where are they coming from?

Comment: How do you sort the scores of your contestants ? `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]` is ascending when `[3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]` is descending and `[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]` doesn't seem sorted to me. Could you light me up here ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
contestants = {"Alice": [], "Dennis": [], "Bob": [], "Eva": [], "Clare": []}
```

Instead of this:

```
contestants = {[("Alice", []),("Dennis", []), ("Bob", []), ("Eva", []), ("Clare", [])]}
```

Also, what exactly is in `racescores` argument? I guess you may want to do something like this:

```
for key, value in enumerate(racescores):
    contestants[key] += value
```

But I am guessing and without data format in `racescores` I can't really help you more.